# Automation within browser to export HTML elements in an XML file

Tags: browser, automation

I have an online store on a marketplace that provides a back-office which features a section that lists all my customers. The problem is that I can't export their contact, I have to copy/paste their info one by one which can be very time consuming. So I was wondering if there was a way to automate this task within my browser. Since their contact is a HTML list, I'd like to target the specific  tags and export them into a compiled XML file.
Is this possible at all?
[EDIT]
Thank you all for your input but it seems out of my reach in term of knowledge. So I've decided to hire a freelancer to perform this task for me.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the HTML that you want to scrape and what you want the XML file to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium might be an option but you didn't provide to many details about the html. Does the page has a rest api? If yes maybe you can call it as json and parse it.